# No menu item for PVS-studio

Tags: pvs-studio

I've installed PVS-Studio 6.12.21152.101 on my computer with Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3. But there isn't any menu item in VS. How can I fix that?

When I run PVS-Studio.exe I got:
[image]

Note that I have Resharper installed. Can this be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I found solution.

I manually installed **PVS-Studio-vs2015.vsix** from `C:\Program Files (x86)\PVS-Studio` and reopen Visual Studio. After that I've got PVS-Studio menu item.

Comment: Yes, manual installation of a plugin is one of the options to solve this problem.

Comment: Had the same problem with VS 2017 Community.  Running PVS-Studio-vs2017.vsix did the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked for me. Actually while being installed, vsix prompted an error message that it can't be installed because of Spy++ window was opened. I suppose installation with .exe installer encountered the same issue but made it silently and stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Try install new version from official site: [download page](https://www.viva64.com/en/pvs-studio-download/).

After approval of the license agreement, integration options will be presented for various supported versions of Microsoft Visual Studio: 
[image]

To make sure that the PVS-Studio tool was correctly installed, you may open the About window (Help/About menu item) (see [Common information on working with the PVS-Studio analyzer](https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0008/))

In addition to using PVS-Studio directly from Visual Studio, you can also run analysis of MSBuild (i.e. Visual C++ and Visual C#)) projects from the command line. [Documentation](https://www.viva64.com/en/m/0035/).

Comment: Thanks a lot but I've done all steps and no result. There is no PVS-Studio tool  in the About window. I've tried to reinstall/reboot computer